# Timezone of the date returned by Date() constructor in chromium browser

Tags: javascript

As per MDN,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

> It's important to keep in mind that while the time value at the heart
> of a Date object is UTC, the basic methods to fetch the date and time
> or its components all work in the local (i.e. host system) time zone
> and offset.

How does chromium browser determine the local time zone and offset?

Comment: It gets it from the OS.

Comment: I want to know how the browser determines it.

Comment: It doesn't. **It gets it from the OS**. Whatever timezone Mac or Windows or Linux thinks you're in is what timezone the browser thinks you're in. If you want to know how *that* is determined, then that is a separate question, and probably not one for Stack Overflow since it isn't even remotely programming related.

Comment: @Phalgun The browser uses System information to determine some info... timezone is between these. Maybe by telling us your goal we could be more accurate.

Comment: @CesareIsHere, In my javascript web application, I want to set the timezone so that subsequent calls to Date() constructor give me the time as per that timezone. I wanted to know how the JS Date() constructor itself find out the timezone and probably hack it so that it can refers to the timezone provided. I do not want to change the timezone at OS level, but only restricted to the JS web app.

Comment: @JaredSmith, Do you recommend another stackexhange communities which are more suitable for these kinds of questions?

Comment: The one you originally asked is ok for stack overflow and I answered it, all good there. If you want to know how the OS knows, that would be a better question for e.g. [superuser.SE](https://superuser.com/) or one of the OS-specific stacks like Unix&Linux. The more-or-less accurate but somewhat facetious answer to "how does the OS know" is "because that's what the user told it": most (all?) OSes will make you input a time zone as part of the initial setup. It can also use [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) to guess *if* it's connected to the internet.

Comment: "In my javascript web application, I want to set the timezone" you can't do that in JS. It's not clear why you would ever want to. Showing things (like Date.prototype.toString) in the local timezone is a convenience for displaying things to the user (who will of course by definition be in the timezone they're in), it shouldn't ever impact the developer. All JS Dates, **all of them** are UTC as it says in the text you quoted.

Comment: "It's not clear why you would ever want to". It is part of a business requirement for a project I'm working on which uses moment-timezone for handling dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser queries the operating system (whichever one you are using) to determine the user's timezone. For instance on the Mac I'm typing this answer on:

```cpp
#if V8_OS_DARWIN
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/mach_time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#endif

#if V8_OS_DARWIN
int64_t ComputeThreadTicks() {
  mach_msg_type_number_t thread_info_count = THREAD_BASIC_INFO_COUNT;
  thread_basic_info_data_t thread_info_data;
  kern_return_t kr = thread_info(
      pthread_mach_thread_np(pthread_self()),
      THREAD_BASIC_INFO,
      reinterpret_cast<thread_info_t>(&thread_info_data),
      &thread_info_count);
  CHECK_EQ(kr, KERN_SUCCESS);

  // We can add the seconds into a {int64_t} without overflow.
  CHECK_LE(thread_info_data.user_time.seconds,
           std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max() -
               thread_info_data.system_time.seconds);
  int64_t seconds =
      thread_info_data.user_time.seconds + thread_info_data.system_time.seconds;
  // Multiplying the seconds by {kMicrosecondsPerSecond}, and adding something
  // in [0, 2 * kMicrosecondsPerSecond) must result in a valid {int64_t}.
  static constexpr int64_t kSecondsLimit =
      (std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max() /
       v8::base::Time::kMicrosecondsPerSecond) -
      2;
  CHECK_GT(kSecondsLimit, seconds);
  int64_t micros = seconds * v8::base::Time::kMicrosecondsPerSecond;
  micros += (thread_info_data.user_time.microseconds +
             thread_info_data.system_time.microseconds);
  return micros;
}
```

You can see here where chromium queries the (again OS-specific) system time.

[Source](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/86d44a8c2b53d016c96683c02fe23ef4f12dd3d6/src/base/platform/time.cc#L49)

If you look at the linked file in the codebase you can see where it has `ifdef`s for all the various supported OS flavors: win32, POSIX, Fuschia, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The timezone is given by the user device (OS).
You can find this information in docs(you linked it in your question):
[image: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#date_format_and_time_zone_conversions]